# bootstrap nav pull-right makes header zoom off screen

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

Upon zooming in mobile the header is zoomed in as well thus the section of my header that is class nav pull-right gets cut off the screen. How can I fix this? perhap fixing the header size to the width of the screen?

```
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
      <div class="signinform" <% if request.path == root_path && current_user.nil? %> style="padding-top: 18px;" <% end %>>
          <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, :html => { :class => "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
              <input id="session_email" name="session[email]" type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Email">
              <input id="session_password" name="session[password]" type="password" class="input-medium" placeholder="Password">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Sign in</button>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I used bootstrap for a header i actually got all the information i needed from this youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPbp1JecLuU&list=FL5jJgNXjcYi4i0QKFe1-NKw&index=3 .

The problem is that Bootstrap header has to be done a certain way in order for everything to work. Things like dynamic resizing are dependant on it being done a ceratin way. This is the way a header should work in general but, you should really check out that youtube video.

Good luck!

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="nav pull-right">
     <div class="signinform" <% if request.path == root_path && current_user.nil? %> style="padding-top: 18px;" <% end %>>
      <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, :html => { :class => "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
          <input id="session_email" name="session[email]" type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="Email">
          <input id="session_password" name="session[password]" type="password" class="input-medium" placeholder="Password">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Sign in</button>
      <% end %>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> <!-- closes class navbar -->
```